# Is there a include equivalent for views in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem with getting the content of a view. The main idea is to load the HTML/PHP content of one view directly into another view.  The controller or model doesn't have to be loaded (but if they can it would be fine).

Actually the problem could be solved by a simple `<?php include 'file' ?>` in my view.
But I would like the CakePHP equivalent in this case.

I don't like to use include because in this case its really slow when I load the site. The main reason why I want to do that, is the ctp would be too big if I just use one file ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use partials?
Create a new view abcd.ctp

and then use `$this->render('abcd')`

http://book.cakephp.org/view/314/Views

Comment: oh i forgot, the main reason because i have to do this, that the ctp file would be tooo big. So render isnt working for me.